# Распарсить сложный JSON-документ в HashSet

Tags: java, json, парсер

Имеется минимальный json-файлик с конфигами:

```
{
  "test": [
    {
      "micro": [
        {
          "attr": "1"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "macro": [
        {
          "attr2": "2"
        },
        {
          "attr3": "3"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Этот файл скорее всего будет расширяться, но структура не будет изменяться.
Есть серия вложенных циклов:

```
for (Object key : json.keySet())
    {

        JSONArray themeArray = ((JSONArray) json.get(key.toString()));
        for (int i = 0; i < themeArray.length(); i++)
        {

            JSONObject langObject = (JSONObject) themeArray.get(i);
            for(Object key2 : langObject.keySet())
            {

                JSONArray langArray = (JSONArray) langObject.get(key2.toString());
                for(int j = 0; j < langArray.length(); j++)
                {

                    JSONObject tagObject = (JSONObject) langArray.get(j);
                    for(Object key3 : tagObject.keySet())
                    {
                        tags.add(tagObject.get(key3.toString()));
                    }

                }

            }

        }
```

Как по-вашему можно это сократить через рекурсию, чтобы на последнем шаге добавлялось в Set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так

```java
void parse(JSONObject json) {
  for (Object key : json.keySet()) {
    Object child = json.get(key.toString());
    if (child instanceof JSONArray) {
      JSONArray arr = (JSONArray) child;
      for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
        parse((JSONObject) arr.get(i));
      }
    } else {
      tags.add(child);
    }
  }
}
```

Если вы хотите, чтобы метод возвращал коллекцию, то проще всего будет написать метод-обертку. А сам метод parse сделать приватным

```java
public Set<Object> publicParse(JSONObject json) {
  Set<Object> res = new HashSet<>;
  parse(res, json);
  return res;
}
```

Comment: Да, это решение подходит, но возможно ли абсолютную единицу сделать с return, чтобы глобальную переменную не создавать?

Comment: @KeyJibo Какую абсолютную единицу? Где здесь глобальная переменная? `tags`? Ну так передавайте ее параметром

Comment: Независимую от внешних переменных в данном случае. Изменять параметры разве хорошо по этике кода?

Comment: @KeyJibo Я не пойму, что вы хотите? Эта функция не зависит от внешних параметров, не изменяет их, не использует глобальных переменных. Что вас не устраивает?

Comment: Я про tags, если его параметром передавать

Comment: @KeyJibo В данном случае метод используется для заполнения коллекции. И это нормально. Если вы хотите, чтобы метод возвращал коллекцию, то проще всего будет написать метод-обертку. А сам метод `parse` сделать приватным

Comment: Извиняюсь за свою докучливость, интересен ход решения мысли. А обёртка такая не является признаком плохого кода?

Comment: @KeyJibo Нет. С чего вы взяли?

Comment: В метод parse передаётся res через параметр, правда обёртка скрывает это, но тем не менее, нельзя ли как-то обойтись без изменения ссылочного параметра?

Comment: @KeyJibo В данном случае нет. Какая-то у вас странная фобия